# How to color nested compound paths Extendscript for Illustrator CS5?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to color the `pathItems` within a `compoundPathItem` in Illustrator. My object looks like a circle inside a circle. No strokes, four paths, two `compoundPathItems` within a `compoundPathItem`.

When I debug with this line: alert(doc.compoundPathItems[0])`I get:-[CompoundPathItem] 
.... which makes sense because I've combined two compoundPathItems.`

However, I cannot seem to get access to the pathItems in order to color them:

```
doc.compoundPathItems[0].compoundPathItems[0].pathItems ... errors out x_x ... 
alert(doc.compoundPathItems[0].pathItems.length) gives me 0 .... T-T
```

Help me understand what's happening here please.

Answer (score 1):

This script will work if all `pageItems` are `compoundItems`, `app.activeDocument.pathItems` will give all `pathItems` in the document. It will also give nested in `compoundPathItem`. So try if it works for you

```
var currentDocument = app.activeDocument;
var pathItems = currentDocument.pathItems;
var redSwatch = currentDocument.swatches.getByName('CMYK Red');
var blueSwatch = currentDocument.swatches.getByName('CMYK Blue');
for (var i = 0; i < pathItems.length; i++) {
    pathItems[i].filled = true;
    pathItems[i].fillColor = redSwatch.color;
    pathItems[i].stroked = true;
    pathItems[i].strokeColor = blueSwatch.color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is the object'shape like a outlined letter "O"? or "◎" > two compoundPathItems within a compoundPathItem

I think any path_item of the compound_path_item colored at last fills color parent object( = compound_path_item).

if letter "O", try this code below

```
#target "Illustrator"
var doc = app.documents[0];
var co_pathitem = doc.compoundPathItems[0].pathItems;

// create colors
var color1 = new RGBColor();
color1.red = 255;

var color2 = new RGBColor();
color2.blue = 255;

// fillcolor red
co_pathitem[0].filled = true;
co_pathitem[0].fillColor = color1;
$.writeln(co_pathitem[0].fillColor.properties()); // => color1

// fillcolor blue
co_pathitem[1].filled = true;
co_pathitem[1].fillColor = color2;
$.writeln(co_pathitem[1].fillColor.properties()); // => color2

// => doc.compoundPathItems[0] will be colored with color2(colored at last)

// but pathItems[0] filled with color1 yet
$.writeln(co_pathitem[0].fillColor.properties()); // => color1

Object.prototype.properties = function (cr) {
  var self = this;
  var cr = cr || ", ";
  var props = [];
  for (var i in self) {
    try {
      props.push(i + ":" + self[i]);
    } catch (e) {
      // props.push(i + ":" + e);
    }
  };
  return props.join(cr);
}
```

Comment: No, sorry.. the shape is like the second one you said "◎"

Answer (score 0):

The point is: if you will unpack target compoundPathItem, you will get not just many pathItems. You will get groupItems, another compoundPathItems, pathItems inside subgroups and so on. Whole structure as it was before creating compoundPath. The only way to get all pathItems is doc.pathItems. But you can do the trick and check if compoundPathItem.layer (it's parent layer) and each pathItem's parent layer are the same layer. So, this worked perfectly for me:

```
var whiteColor = new CMYKColor();
whiteColor.black = 0;

var doc = app.activeDocument;
//....defining targetLayer here
var whitePathItem = targetLayer.compoundPathItems[0]; //Target layer contains our compound Path
var parentLayer = whitePathItem.layer;

for(var i = 0; i < doc.pathItems.length; i++) {
    var pathItem = doc.pathItems[i];
    if(pathItem.layer == parentLayer) pathItem.fillColor = whiteColor;
}
```

Just checking parent layer, that's the trick!